# Local data store for small data with high performance

Tags: java

So, this is my scenario.

I have millions of events coming in and I don't want to throw that data directly to my DB. I want a "batch"  operation, where the java code holds the events coming in till it reaches a threshold (say every 10seconds) and them do a batch insert to the primary database.

I also need fault tolerance since if the machine crashes, I don't want to loose the data.
I am considering hsqldb for to hold those events (will be around 10k) for 10seconds.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The only way to achieve fault tolerance is redundancy. There's no way to guarantee processing with a single machine. Once you have redundancy in place, you can start to think about scaling, by having each machine in the cluster responsible for storing only part of the data, using a framework such as Zookeeper to coordinate between machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want millions of entires per second AND persistence you could try. [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle)
You can have a different process consuming the data so if your program dies, the data will still be written to the data base. (Also your main process won't be slowed does by having to perform the database updates)  It also support replication over TCP to multiple machines.

A simple example based on this test [HERE](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle/blob/master/src/test/java/vanilla/java/chronicle/impl/IndexedChronicleTest.java)

```
 // create a Chronicle for reading or writing.
 String basePath = TMP + File.separator + "deleteme.ict";
 IndexedChronicle tsc = new IndexedChronicle(basePath);

 // create a handle to excerpts in the chronicle.
 Excerpt excerpt = tsc.createExcerpt();

 // add 1024 entries.
 int counter = 1;
 for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        excerpt.startExcerpt(129);
        for (int j = 0; j < 128; j += 8)
            excerpt.writeLong(counter++);
        excerpt.write(-1);
        excerpt.finish();
 }

 // somewhere else read the file
    int counter2 = 1;
    Excerpt excerpt2 = tsc.createExcerpt();
    while (excerpt2.nextIndex()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 128; j += 8) {
            long actual = excerpt2.readLong();
            long expected = counter2++;
            if (expected != actual)
                assertEquals(expected, actual);
        }
        assertEquals(-1, excerpt2.readByte());
        excerpt2.finish();
    }
    assertEquals(counter, counter2);
```

This allows you to batch up as they become available to minimise the risk of it not being added to the database.  When nextIndex() returns false you commit the transaction for the batch, wait a bit and repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not sure about this. 

The data which I need to flush to my primary DB will be around 10k records (extremely simple schema, like K-V pairs). Does java-chronicle give me the ability: 1. Keep writing, 2. Read all at once, 3. Flush it. I see in `/testing` you have some examples, but still a little confused about the pragmatic approach to use this lib. Can you please point me to a "Getting Started" link or something?

Comment: The writer can keep writing without knowing what the reader is doing and isn't slowed down but it no matter how far it behind.  The reader can read how it wants up to how much has been written. This library doesn't require an flushing as such.  It assumes you will rotate the files one a daily or weekly basis.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler, posted an Article of his LMAX architecture, which allows millions of transactions in main memory, whith the possibility to restore in case of failure.

At least you should take a look: http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring that your problem is DB load, not process load.  This raises the question to me why you expect batch operations to be cheaper, from your question so far it just sounds like you would rather pay $600 an hour than $10 a minute but the load will be just as bad.

If you can handle batch operations cheaply then you merely need to cache into an intermedium to which saving is cheap, then load from there.  The two things that come to mind are writing to flat files in JSON, and using Memcached (also JSON probably), where the loading happens in a separate process (or threadpool).  You will need to ensure atomicity between the two.  There may be more out-of-the-box solutions for this, I'll leave to more knowledgeable answers to come upw ith.

Depending on how bad you expect crashes to be, you can also set a shutdown hook to dump before machine crashes although this is questionable practice at best.

Comment: Yes, my problem is DB load. Writing to local file will be expensive vs  using hsqldb. Memcached might be an overkill for such a small (and temporary) dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Batch operations are actually handled on database level. Database merges multiple transactions in single (or a few) writes into transaction log, that the writes are moved from transaction log to tables, but they are grouped to minimize disk writes. At least with **Oracle**. This is why it is so efficient, and so expensive. But it can be so, that **PostgreSQL** will fulfill your expectations. Test first.

When it comes to database reads, there's also intensive caching from the database's site. But parsing SQL is expensive, so using client cache is very good option. Consider **EhCache**. It supports 2 levels of caching: a predefined number of items is hold in memory, and other set is overflowed to disk (you can use only memory caching if you want). The read time from memory cache is about the **HashMap** access time. Of course the more RAM you have, the efficienter your memory cache will be.

When it comes to fault tolerance, databases guarantee that, cache not. This is issue only with writes, not reads. Don't try to implement something on your own with hsqldb for example. **Disk writes are always expensive**. You won't write anything better than Oracle because you don't have such many people and time :) Their mechanism with transaction log is **very** efficient. And when system crashes, the operations are restored from that log, as long as the **commit** was performed.